# Ajax calls with JSONP doesn't work. Callback not provided

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I am trying to make a api call like this:

```
 var url = 'http://[api link]?callback=?';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        console.dir(json.sites);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

but in the browser it always shows in this format: [image: Error Image]

And in fiddler I get this following error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: A callback parameter was not provided in the request URI.]
WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp.JsonpMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType) + 320
System.Net.Http.Formatting.DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable` 1 formatters) + 199
System.Web.Http.Results.NegotiatedContentResult` 1.Execute(HttpStatusCode statusCode, T content, IContentNegotiator contentNegotiator, HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable` 1 formatters) + 103
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value, HttpConfiguration configuration) + 235
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateErrorResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, Func` 2 errorCreator) + 298
System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.DefaultExceptionHandler.Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context) + 152
System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.DefaultExceptionHandler.HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) + 12
System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling. & lt;
HandleAsyncCore & gt;
d__0.MoveNext() + 136
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) + 144
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) + 84
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter` 1.GetResult() + 49
System.Web.Http. & lt;
SendAsync & gt;
d__0.MoveNext() + 1584
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) + 144
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) + 84
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter` 1.GetResult() + 49
System.Web.Http.WebHost. & lt;
ProcessRequestAsyncCore & gt;
d__0.MoveNext() + 624
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) + 144
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) + 84
System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) + 98
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 606
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean & amp; completedSynchronously) + 288
```

In the.js file where the call is made, I have defined a
function like this:

```
jsonCallback = function(data) {

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Screen Shot of ajax error:
[image]

EDIT:

WebapiConfig.cs

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    //add support for JSONP
    var formatter = new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(jsonFormatter, "cb");
    config.Formatters.Insert(0, formatter);

    //Add Support CORS
    config.EnableCors();
```

Comment: callback function name and the jsonpCallback property match exactly in text and casing?

Comment: @jmogera Try with `success: function(json, textStatus, jqxhr){console.dir(jqxhr.responseText);},error: function(jqxhr) {console.dir(jqxhr.responseText);}` ; if possible, can post `responseText` ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 i code doesn't make it that far. I get 500 internal server error. When I look inside the call response with fiddler, i see the error list above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does it return if you try this?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://[api link]', // without the callback at the end
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function (result) {
     $('#jsonp').html(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: please look at the screen shot I have added.

Comment: @jmogera Open the link http://[api link] which doesn't work in browser. Does it work? Also look at the samples in the WebApiContrib project https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp

Comment: in the browser the data does load in a xml format. I added code that I have in webapiconfig.cs file. I will attempt to do it based on how the link above suggests.

Comment: Tried the direction described in link you provided, but the same error. In the browser it runs fine and data is returned in xml format. I have also added some code which will show you how I was using JSONP formatting.

Comment: @jmogera how does your javascript look now? could you show it?

Comment: I got it work! i commented out the code I had in webapiconfig, and only enabled code in global.asax file.

Comment: @jmogera congratulation:)

Comment: can you help this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767558/passing-credentials-not-working