# passing credentials not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I am trying to make a json call, by passing the credentials. If the user is already logged into the system using Sql Membership, how can I pass the credentials without getting this:

[image: log in image]

Here is the code that calls the web.api:

NOTE: call is being made from cross domain: i.e. www.project.com -> api.project.com

```
var url = 'http://api.project.com/LookUps/uploadtypes?callback=?';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    jsonpCallback: 'handler',
    contentType: "application/javascript",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (json, textStatus, jqxhr) { console.log(jqxhr.responseText); },
    error: function (json, textStatus, jqxhr) { console.log(jqxhr.responseText); }
 });
```

Edit:

I still get the login when authentication is disabled. Is there another place for the window authentication setting?

[image]

Comment: The pop up is for windows authentication. I think you need to disable windows authentication for the api project deployed on iis server.

Comment: Do yo want to enable windows authentication?

Comment: its form based authentication that I need to enable. I am trying to pass the credentials from my web app to the web api project. Sound it ask for the user name and password like that even though I am passing in as credentials.

Comment: What is the domain on your forms auth cookie?

Comment: http://app.project.com

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this popup you have to change your URL to following.

var url = 'http://username:password@api.project.com/LookUps/uploadtypes?callback=?';

replace username - with actual username
and password with actual password.